# Achieving laziness and memoization

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Laziness is a corner stone in the book Purely Functional Data Structures, but it is not clearly described how he obtains it, at least to me.
I thought I only needed to write:

```
datatype 'a susp = $ of 'a
fun force ($x) = x
fun plus (x, y) = $case (x, y) of ($m, $n) => m + n
```

But then I get the error:

```
- use "ch4.sml";;
[opening ch4.sml]
ch4.sml:3.20 Error: syntax error: inserting  ORELSE
[unexpected exception: Compile]

uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:19.24-19.46
../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:45.54
../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:306.20-306.23
../compiler/TopLevel/interact/interact.sml:65.13-65.16
```

---

I tried modifying the function to

`fun plus (x, y) = $(print "Evaluating...\n"; force x + force y)`

But calling it with `plus ($4, $5)` evaluated it and didn't memoize it because it returns `$ 9` instead of `$ plus(force $4, force $5)` and it printed `Evaluating...` both times.

```
- plus ($4, $5);;
Evaluating...
val it = $ 9 : int susp
- plus ($4, $5);;
Evaluating...
val it = $ 9 : int susp
```

---

I'd also like to obtain the keyword `lazy`, but I'm not sure whether SML New Jersey supports this, whether it was implemented by Chris Okasaki, or that it's manually desugared.
The keyword is highlighted in my editor but when writing

`fun lazy plus ($x, $y) = $ (x + y)`

I get that `lazy` is the function taking two parameters `plus` and `($x, $y)` as given by the type:

`val lazy = fn : 'a -> int susp * int susp -> int susp`

---

My question boils down to **How do I obtain laziness and memoization in SML New Jersey?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable laziness and add some parentheses (the `$` in the book has peculiar parsing rules):

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.83 [built: Thu May 31 09:04:19 2018]
- Control.lazysml := true;
[autoloading]
[ ... boring details ...] 
[autoloading done]
val it = () : unit
- open Lazy;
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
opening Lazy

  datatype 'a susp = $ of 'a
- fun plus (x, y) = $(case (x, y) of ($m, $n) => m + n);
val plus = fn : int susp * int susp -> int susp
-  val x = plus($4, $5);
val x = $$ : int susp
- fun force ($x) = x;
val force = fn : 'a susp -> 'a
- force x;
val it = 9 : int
- fun lazy plus ($x, $y) = $ (x + y);
val plus = fn : int susp * int susp -> int susp
val plus_ = fn : int susp * int susp -> int
```

Note that this does not memoize `plus`.

Comment: This works! The `plus` function is not memoized but the suspension is, e.g., `fun lazy delayed ($x) = $(print "Evaluating...\n"; x)` and then binding it with `val x = delayed ($5)`, and forcing it twice `force x; force x` only prints once. Thank you! However, I don't understand why `fun delayed x = $(case x of ($q) => (print "Evaluating...\n"; q))` doesn't work. When binding it as `val q = delayed ($4)` already prints before being the forced (it is still memoized though). But I'd like to know why the print is not suspended.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why both `Control.lazysml := true` and `open Lazy` are necessary and what they do?

Comment: The former enables lazy evaluation in the compiler. `open Lazy;` opens the `Lazy` module so you can use unqualified names. (Also, note that `lazy` is not a function.)

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this? As far as I can tell from the documentation, the [`Control`](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/Compiler/pages/control.html) structure does not seem to include `lazysml`. The `Lazy` structure is also not really documented as far as I can tell, and the link to the `LAZYCONTROL` signature leads nowhere (though some documentation can be found [here](https://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs430/smlnj/doc/Compiler/pages/lazycontrol.html) for some reason).

Comment: The documentation of the Control structure is pretty miserable, and I can't really remember where I found anything over three years ago.  The `lazysml` is there in my 110.99.3 version, though.